# Calculating Down Range and Cross Range Coordinates

Tags: trigonometry

I have a laser pointer located at:

```
x = 0 in
y = -23.53 in
z = 50.82 in
```

When pointing the laser in space, I keep the elevation angle fixed but vary the azimuth angle. In order to calculate the points at which the beam hits the ground, I use the following equations:

```
r = z/sind(-el) 
DownRange = r*cosd(el)*cosd(az) + x 
CrossRange = r*cosd(el)*sind(az) + y
```

In comparing to a solid model, my DownRange calculation appears to be correct, but the CrossRange does not. Any idea what's wrong?

@barrycarter:

Here are the inputs and outputs to the CAD model and my equations:

```
Case 1
AZ = 0 deg
EL = -45 deg
Results:
DownRange = 4.24 ft
CrossRange = 1.96 ft

Case 2
AZ = 20
EL = 45
DownRange = 3.98 ft
CrossRange = 3.41 ft

Inputs and Outputs to my equations:
Case 1 (inputs same as CAD models)
DownRange = 4.24 ft
CrossRange = 1.96 ft

Case 2 (inputs same as CAD models)
DownRange = 3.98 ft
CrossRange = -0.5124 ft
```

I realized that if I take the absolute value of my Y component, then my results seem to match up with the CAD model. I still don't understand why that is the case.

Comment: At first glance, this looks ok to me. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: when i compare it to a CAD model, which has been proven, my results don't match up for the CrossRange values.

Comment: What results do you get and what results does the model get?

Comment: Cosine is an even function. The cosine of 45 degrees is the same as the cosine of -45 degrees. You may be computing it wrong in the negative case.

Comment: @barrycarter I'm not sure what you mean by negative case.

Comment: Why `r = z/sind(-el)`. That would r negative when el is between 0 and 90 degrees (which occurs in case 2). I think you mean `r= |z/sind(el)|` don't you, where |x| is the absolute value of x.

Comment: @barrycarter r=z/sind(-el) because the laser pointer is suspended above ground and points down in a negative angle. should I just use the abs(x) method instead?

Comment: In spherical coordinates, `r` usually refers to a radius (or distance), which is always a positive number. You might be doing things differently and having `r` refer to both radius and direction. I suggest at least trying the standard spherical coordinates model.